# How does one conclude that the beams in this problem will be inclined?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis

I was practicing some problems of axially loaded members in Strength of Materials, when I stumbled upon this one:

[image]

Two initially horizontal beams connected by aluminum and copper wires. Both the wires have same length initially and diameters $d_1 $and $d_2 $ . A load P is applied at the midspan of the beams (points E and F). It was asked to compute the displacement of point E.

The steps followed in solving such problems are:

- Form an equilibrium equation
- Form the compatibility equation which considers the deformation in the system

While forming the compatibility equation, I, without a second thought concluded that, okay, both the wires elongate by the same amount so I can just equate the elongations of each wire to get the forces in them and then finally the displacement of point E will be equal to the deformation in each wire.

However, when checked the solution found that the beam actually inclines after the load is applied, which completely changes the solution.

How does one conclude in such systems, when the horizontal beam is going to get inclined and when not?

Comment: You have got your logic back-to-front. If you want to assume two things are equal, you need a *reason* to assume that. Otherwise, assume they are different! If they turn out to be equal the math will tell you that.

Answer (score 2):

They won't deform by the same amount. Assuming that the horizontally beams are deformable bodies (i.e. not rigid), you can calculate the forces acting on each of the corners by simple statics. Aluminum is experiencing P/2 load on each end, and so is Copper. A difference in Elastic Modulus exist between these two materials, so for the same equal force on both materials, they have to result in different strains therefore, different deformations.

Moreover, assuming that both wires have different diameters, that also causes a change in the stiffness of each wire and hence result in different displacements.

As far as the rigid case is considered for the horizontally beams, then it is true that both wires will have equal deformations. But the load distribution will be different now (it cannot be assumed P/2 for both wires). The wire with greater stiffness (which depends on E and Cross sectional area) will take higher force.

Comment: Couldn't the beams still get inclined (unequal deformations in the wires), when it is rigid? Beams could change their angles with the horizontal and still be rigid.

Comment: It cannot. Cause for changing its angle, you have to apply the load not exactly in the center, instead closer to one of the bodies. Right now, there are no net moment acting on the whole system, but there will be when you change the load to not act in the center of the horizontal beams.

Answer (score 1):

Basically AC and BD can be thought of as two springs. Because the equivalent "spring constant" is given by:

$$k_{eq}= \frac{EA}{L}$$

you need to calculate the "spring constant" for copper and aluminium. If the spring constant is the same, then the elongation will be the same.

If one of the is larger (e.g. $k_c> k_{al}$), then the copper will deform less (the same force will cause less deformation), and therefore the CD beam will tilt.

Answer (score 1):

The deflection of E depends on the L length of the wires.
if L is long enough to allow the softer wire to expand ultimately longer than the distance of the beam AB it will never receive half of P and will be just riding along.

Most of the load will be carried by the stiffer wire and beam AB will rotate 90 degrees.

let's call the stiffness of the wires K1 and K2.

The extension of the 2 wires will be approximately equal to the extension of a wire with the sum of the stiffness and a rotation of $arcsin((P/2)/(K1L)-(P/2)/K2L)/ AB).$ But the new geometry incrementally changes the stress requiring a few iterations.

But this is approximately correct only in small rotation angles. when the two wires stiffness is large more complex analisis is needed.